# How kill grandchild processes

Tags: bash

Killing children in BASH looks easy task.
But my script makes children inside UNIX conveyor.
And this standard techniques don't work.

I have a BASH script like this

```
ls -1 | { while read line ; do 
                python -c 'while 1: pass' &
          done ; }
while : ; do sleep 1 ; done
```

The parent process should wait for Ctrl+C or another signal to stop all background
subprocesses doing infinite loop.

There are problems:

```
jobs -p  # print nothing so trap hook cannot kill anybody
```

Second is a trap defined inside curly braces is not called at all. 
In such case the infinite loop is inside the braces too.

I have a last resort solution to put pids from $! into a tmp file but 
look cumbersome for me.

### Attempt 2

I've rewritten code with new suggestions below but there is still no success.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                        

echo "my pid is $$"
exit_func() {
    echo "pid in exit $(echo $$)"
    echo "ps $(ps --no-headers --ppid $$ -o pid)"
    echo "pgrep $(pgrep -P $$)"
    echo "pstree $(pstree -p $$)"
}

trap 'exit_func' EXIT

ls -1 / | {
    while read a ; do
        python -c 'while 1: pass' &
        echo -n " $!"
    done
}

while : ; do : ; done
```

Utils ps, pgrep, and pstree just cannot see python children.

```
[dan@localhost]$ ./testtrap.sh 
my pid is 17848
 17851 17852 17853 17854 17855 17856 17857 17858 17859 17860 17861 17862 17863 17864 17865 17866 17867 17868 17869 17870 17871 17872 17873  C-c C-\
cpid in exit 17848
ps 17875
pgrep 17877
pstree testtrap.sh(17848)---testtrap.sh(17879)---pstree(17880)

[dan@localhost]$ ps 
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
17851 pts/2    00:00:12 python
17852 pts/2    00:00:12 python
17853 pts/2    00:00:12 python
17854 pts/2    00:00:12 python
17855 pts/2    00:00:12 python
17856 pts/2    00:00:14 python
17857 pts/2    00:00:12 python
17858 pts/2    00:00:15 python
17859 pts/2    00:00:12 python
17860 pts/2    00:00:12 python
17861 pts/2    00:00:15 python
17862 pts/2    00:00:12 python
17863 pts/2    00:00:12 python
17864 pts/2    00:00:12 python
17865 pts/2    00:00:12 python
17866 pts/2    00:00:14 python
17867 pts/2    00:00:12 python
17868 pts/2    00:00:12 python
17869 pts/2    00:00:12 python
17870 pts/2    00:00:15 python
17871 pts/2    00:00:12 python
17872 pts/2    00:00:12 python
17873 pts/2    00:00:12 python
17959 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
27560 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
[dan@localhost]$
```

Comment: consider that the infinite loop may be running so fast that the keyboard Ctrl-C gets lost (this does happen, but sometimes if you press Ctrl-C 10x very rapidly, one of them will get thru). (Opps, I see you have a `sleep 1` already in your test, but maybe you want to add something like `echo "looping for the $((i++))'th time"` at the top of your loops.) Good luck.

Comment: see my revised comment.